# Iterate over collection of input objects with identical attributes: Java Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, loops, selenium, collections, webdriver

I have tried some of the examples of iteration already provided here, but I am not yet able to iterate over a collection of input fields, all of which have identical identification attributes: , and .

I need to iterate over all these objects and add the same string to each.
The following code assigns the string to the first instance of the input field, but it will not move on to the next instance:

```
List<WebElement> allSumInsuredFields = driver.findElements(By.id("ctl00__txtSumInsured"));
Iterator<WebElement> itr = allSumInsuredFields.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){

    if (driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_txtSumInsured")).getText().equals("")) ;
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_txtSumInsured")).sendKeys("£250000");

    itr.next(); 
}
```

Comment: `id` attribute in DOM is supposed to be unique. Are you sure all of the elements have same `id`?

Comment: Sorry,  made a mistake.  Every instance of the SumInsured field does have a unique id: ctl00_wnCore_rptCoverageSelections_ctl01_UnitContainerControl1_ctl00_AnimalDetailInputPanel_txtSumInsured
The part that shows ctl01 becomes ctl02, ctl03 and so on for each instance of the field.  The trouble is, I do not know in advance how many instances of this field there will be in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your code is that inside your loop you use `driver.findElement` to acquire the element to work on. Not only is this doing *extra work* but **this makes your algorithm incorrect**. The `findElement` methods (in the singular) return *the first element* they find. So in your code, it does not matter how many times the loop iterates, it is always going to operate on the first element with the id you want.

As Saifur mentioned, you should be using `getAttribute("value")` to get the value of an `input` element. So something like this is what you need:

```
for(WebElement el : driver.findElements(By.id("ctl00__txtSumInsured"))) {
    if (el.getAttribute("value").equals(""))        
        el.sendKeys("something");
}
```

Contrarily to Saifur, I'm not suggesting that you use an explicit wait before this loop. Whether or not you need one, and what form it should take really depends on the application being tested. You did not say enough in the question to make this determination. An extra, unnecessary check is not harmless: it makes your Selenium script slower. If you get into the habit of having unnecessary checks you can add *minutes* of running time to your script. And a check that does not check for the exact right thing is actually harmful.

Answer (score 1):

Does not need to use extra iterator

```
By byId = By.id("ctl00__txtSumInsured");

//Explicit wait just to make sure the elements are loaded properly
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byId));

List<WebElement> allSumInsuredFields = driver.findElements(byId);

//Now iterate through List and do whatever you want
for(WebElement ele:allSumInsuredFields)
{
  if(ele.getAttribute("value").equals(""));        
  ele.sendKeys("something");

}
```

**EDIT**
You don't use `getText()` to get the value of input textbox You should replace that with `getAttribute("value")` and that will return the value

```
if (driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_txtSumInsured")).getAttribute("value").equals("")) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it like this:

C#

```
List<IWebElement> allSumInsuredFields = driver.findElements(By.Id("ctl00__txtSumInsured"));

foreach (var element in allSumInsuredFields)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Text))
       {
           element.SendKeys("£250000");
       }
    }
```

Java:

```
for(WebElement element : allSumInsuredFields)     
           if (element.getAttribute("value") != null && 
              !element.getAttribute("value").isEmpty())
           {
               element.sendKeys("£250000");
           }
```

Apologies if the Java syntax is incorrect, but you get what I'm aiming at here.

Comment: OP has tagged java. The script in java would have been better.